# Angular scroll issue when open one outlet from another outlet

Tags: javascript, angular, router, router-outlet

I have problem with angular outlets. In routes i have such strucutre:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'path',
    component: MyComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'modal-route-1',
        component: FirstModal,
        outlet: 'modal',
      },
      {
        path: 'modal-route-2',
        component: SecondModal,
        outlet: 'modal',
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I can navigate from `FirstModal` to `SecondModal`. The problem is that if i have scroll in `MyComponent` and navigate from it `FirstModal` everything works perfect and scroll disappear. But when i navigate to `SecondModal` from `FirstModal` - scroll from `MyComponent` is restored. How to fix this?

Comment: Can you show in the question which container has the scollbar?

Comment: It appears you are using *both* child routes and named (auxiliary) routes for your modals. Was that intended? Normally you would use one or the other.

Comment: @DeborahK What do you mean? I have route, for example page with user info: `users/25`. On that page i have button 'Settings' which open modal with route `user/25/(modal:settings)` and from this modal i can open another modal with route `user/25/(modal:security)`

Comment: @ConnorsFan body has the scroll bar

Comment: I assume what you have above is just sample code? Because normally you would not use the `children` property and then define both child routes to aux outlets.

Comment: Adding the `children` property is telling it to display the child routes in the parent's router outlet. But using the `outlet` property is telling it to display the routes in the aux (named) router outlet. So you would use one or the other. But I'm guessing that the above is not your actual code.